# How to find out what a design pattern is called

Tags: names, ui-element

When I see a design pattern that I want to study and use, how can I find out what it's called, so I can research it?

For example, I came across this [neumorphic ui pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=neumorphism%20ui&sxsrf=ALeKk01eYCD4BprI-ZNq2VWBATLolhLy1g:1610280579088&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijsZ7PqpHuAhXVHc0KHQMDCv4Q_AUoAXoECAUQAw&biw=1366&bih=625#imgrc=Q_5ckGjTkfnnRM), but only stumbled on its name by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the following sites, or use them in your search queries:

- Mobbin Design
- Land-book
- UI-Patterns
- Design DB
- Pttrns
- Webframez
- UI Jar
- Screen Lane
- Abduzeedo
- Mobile Patterns
- Lovely UI

Answer (score 2):

You could use tools such as google image search to check for similar images and get a possible search term.

[image: google image search]